# How to show value labels in MS Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have written code for MS chart in View of my MVC . My code goes like:

```
    var filePathName = Model.UniqueName;
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)

     .AddTitle("OAP Percetage")
     .DataBindTable(Model.Charting, "Month")
     .AddLegend("Series")
     .SetXAxis("Months")
     .SetYAxis("Percentage") 
     .Save(path: filePathName);`
```

Now I want to know the method by which I can display value labels. I have 4 y values per X value. I don't want the code for controller. I want to code only in this view for the chart.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) not what you are looking for?

Comment: But in this they haven't provided solution on how to put value labels. They have only show picture of a chart with value labels.